# Add multiple dataframes to one dataframe without overwriting the existing dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 332 csv files and each file has the same number of variables and the same format, and I need to create a function that every time the user calls it, can specify the folder where the csv files are located and the id of the csv files they want to store in one data frame.

The name of the files follows the next format: 001.csv, 002.csv ... 332.csv.

```
data <- function(directory, id_default = 1:332){
setwd(paste0("/Users/", directory))

id <- id_default

for(i in length(id)){
    if(i < 10){
        aux <- paste0("00",i)
        filename <- paste0(aux,".csv")
    }else if(i < 100){
        aux <- paste0("0", i)
        filename <- paste0(aux, ".csv")
    }else if(i >= 100){
        filename <- paste0(i, ".csv")
    }
    my_dataframe <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filename, read.csv))

}
my_dataframe #Print dataframe
```

}

But the problem is that it only store the last csv file, it seems that every time that enters the loop it overwrites the dataframe with the last csv file. 
How do I fix it? Plz help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading multiple files and calculating mean based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640594/reading-multiple-files-and-calculating-mean-based-on-user-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we are looping over the last 'id', i.e the `length`.  Instead it should be

```
for(i in 1:length(id))
```

Or more correctly

```
for(i in seq_along(id))
```

---

In addition to the issue with looping, the `if/else if` is not really needed.  We could use `sprintf`

```
filenames <- sprintf('%03d.csv', id)
```

i.e.

```
data <- function(directory, id_default = 1:332){
     setwd(paste0("/Users/", directory))
     filenames <-  sprintf('%03d.csv', id_default)
     do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv))
 }
```

Comment: Yet another duplicate of the Johns Hopkins *R Programming* first programming assignment... The 332 files are the giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

A tidy solution will use `purrr` (better than a loop for this task): https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html

```
library(tidyverse)
directory <- "directory"
id <- c(1,20,300)

# add leading 0s with stringr's str_pad
id %<>% str_pad(3, pad = "0")
```

It is best to avoid using `setwd()` like this.

Instead, add `directory` to the file paths.

```
paths <- str_c(directory, "/", id, ".csv")

# map files to that function (similar to a loop) and stack rows
map_dfr(paths, read_csv)
```

Even better, use `here()`--it makes file paths work: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

```
paths <- str_c(
      here::here(directory, id),
      ".csv")

# map files to that function (similar to a loop) and stack rows
map_dfr(paths, read_csv)
```

Your example seems to want to make the default id's 1:332. If we wanted all files in the directory, we could use `paths <- list.files(here::here(directory))`.

```
read_my_data <- function(directory, id = 1:332){
  paths <- str_c(
      here::here(directory, str_pad(id, 3, pad = "0")),
      ".csv")
  map_dfr(paths, read_csv)
} 

read_my_data("directory")
```

If you need to combine files from multiple directories in parallel, you can use `pmap_dfr()`